# How to set for loop array values to a bean

Tags: java, spring

I have the following loop in a controller class:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= locationArr.length - 1; i++) {
    data.put(idArr[i], locationArr[i]);
    locationBean.setLocation_name(locationArr[i]);
}
```

My Bean looks like :

```
 public class LocationBean {
     private String region_id;
     private String region_name;
     private String location_id;
     private String location_name;

     //getters and setters  
 }
```

I am trying to set location_name as setLocation_name(locationArr[i]);
But only getting last values of the loop [i] is being assigned.

Comment: Well, your LocationBean only has a single location_name. Not sure how you expected to set multiple location names in it from an array. maybe you meant to create multiple Instances of LocationBean and everyone with a different location.

Comment: Then how to set multiple locations to it.I have tried using list

Comment: `Collection`, array, ... simply with `List<String> locations_name` but I would use instead a `List<Location>` and merge the `id` and `name` into a `Location` bean. If note you will have to read two list (location_name and location_id) and insure there the index matches

Comment: I mean private list location_name;

Comment: can you please elaborate I am very basic to java

Comment: @vijaymahanthesh can you give some informations about you model?

Comment: @vijaymahanthesh can you give some informations about you model? Fo exemple relation beetwenn location and region. Is each location has a region? Is each location linked to a region? when you update a location what do you have as input (only  location id, and location name? or regionid and location name? or other?) give us somme information to help you..

Answer (score 0):

If you like to have multiple location names you can do that by e.g. a List or more general any Collection if order does not matter.

Here an example:

```
public class LocationBean {
   private String region_id;
   private String region_name;
   private String location_id;
   private List<String> locationNames = new ArrayList<>();

   //getters and setters 
   public List<String> getLocationNames() {
        return locationNames;
   } 
}
```

usage in your loop:

```
locationBean.getLocationNames().add(locationArr[i]);
```

I did not refactor all your example code to be complient to the java naming convention. You should name your variables in camel case.

Comment: I have tried this,it will give output like this: region1  [loc3, loc2, loc1, loc5, loc4]

Comment: I need each location separately  so that i can edit or update each location induvidually

Answer (score 0):

## LocationBean with a List

You want to store every location name, not set ONE value. So you want a method `addLocationName` store it into a `Collection`

```
locationBean.addLocationName(locationArr[i]);
```

That method is simple, it will add every `String` into a `List<String>`

```
private List<String> locationsName;
private List<String> locationsId;


public LocationBean (){
    locationsName = new ArrayList<String>();
    locationsId= new ArrayList<String>();
}

public boolean addLocationName(string locationName){
    return this.locationsName.add(locationName);
}

public boolean addLocationId(string locationId){
    return this.locationsId.add(locationId);
}
```

Of course, you would need to do the same with `location_id`, so a `Bean` would be smarter :

```
public class Location{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    
    public Location(String id, String name){ ... }
    //constructor and getter
}
```

and simply use a `List<Location>` instead. That way, both `id` and `name` are stored together.

```
public boolean addLocation(Location location){
    return this.locations.add(location);
}
```

or passing the values

```
public boolean addLocation(String id, String name){
    return this.locations.add(new Location(id, name));
}
```

---

## List of LocationBean

Or your bean should only have one location and then this is in your loop that you need to store every instance of `LocationBean` into a `List<LocationBean>` (don't forget to create a new instance each time`

```
List<LocationBean> locations = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i <= locationArr.length - 1; i++) {
    locationBean = new LocationBean(); //new instance each time

    locationBean.setLocation_name(locationArr[i]);

    locations.add(locationBean); //add into the list
}
```

Comment: I have tried ,it will give output like this: region1 [loc3, loc2, loc1, loc5, loc4] , I need each location separately so that i can edit or update each location induvidually

Comment: @vijaymahanthesh You have at the end of the answer the solution where you actually want one `LocationBean` per loop and set it into the list. (This was not really clear what you want so I put both solutions)

Answer (score 0):

Either u can create a list of LocationBean objects :

```
ArrayList <LocationBean> locationBeanList = new ArrayList <LocationBean>)();

for (int i = 0; i <= locationArr.length - 1; i++) {
        data.put(idArr[i], locationArr[i]);
        locationBean = new LocationBean();
        locationBean.setLocation_name(locationArr[i]);
        locationBeanList.add(locationBean);

    }
```

Or, u can create list of locations in single location bean

```
 public class LocationBean {
 private String region_id;
 private String region_name;
 private String location_id;
 private List<String> location_name_list = new ArrayList<String>();

 //getters and setters  
 }

List<String> locationList = new ArrayList <String>();
 for (int i = 0; i <= locationArr.length - 1; i++) {
        data.put(idArr[i], locationArr[i]);

        locationList.add(locationArr[i]);

    }

locationBean.setLocation_name_list(locationList );
```

Comment: I have tried with first one,it will give output like this: region1 [loc3, loc2, loc1, loc5, loc4] ,    
I need each location separately so that i can edit or update each location induvidually

Comment: That is, each location in separate bean

Comment: I have multiple locations under each region

Comment: I am getting only last value of the loop

Comment: In that case you can use the second approach. Each bean will have a list of locations under it which you can update/modify individually using list operations.

Comment: I have tried even with this the output looks likeregion1  [loc3, loc2, loc1, loc5, loc4]